# The number of mutually-unbiased bases in dimension $d$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, hilbert-space

[This recent answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/391139/8563) points to the concept of a [mutually-unbiased pair of bases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutually_unbiased_bases), which are orthonormal bases $\{e_1,\ldots, e_d\}$ and $\{f_1,\ldots, f_d\}$ of a $d$-dimensional Hilbert space $\mathcal H$ such that the overlap between basis vectors of the two bases, $|\langle e_i,f_j\rangle|$, is constant and independent of $i$ and $j$.

As Dr. Mitchison points out, a reasonable amount is known about the total number $m$ of pairwise-mutually-unbiased bases that one can have in a given complex vector space as a function of its dimension, including the case of a power-of-a-prime dimension $d=p^n$ having a maximal $m=d+1$ MUBs possible.

I would like to ask a bit more about the details of that result:

- Are any other infinite families of dimensions known at which the maximal number of MUBs is known? Are any finite cases known?
- If the latter but not the former, what's the largest dimension $d$ to have a known maximal $m$?
- What's the smallest dimension $d$ for which the maximal number of possible MUBs is an open question?

It would also be good to have solid (and, if possible, accessible) references for any quoted results.

Comment: As far as linearity goes one choice should be enough.

Comment: I don't know of any example of a non-prime-power dimension where the number of mutually unbiased bases is known. In simplest case of $d=6$ there is evidence that the number is $3$ but no proof as far as I know. Higher than that relatively little is known.

Comment: You might want to look up the work of Stefan Weigert from York U. in the UK on this topic.  (He has a GoogleScholar profile).  He and his students have done what is probably the most extensive search for mutually unbiased based in composite dimensions.  See as an example https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.78.042312